# Terraform - Unable to intiate terraform

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terraform, command-line-interface

I am trying to initiate terraform on visual studio code - insiders.

Points:

1. I have downloaded the terraform executable file and i am able to launch it on command prompt.
2. When to run the command terraform init command on visual studio code - insider i get the following error message. Please find the error message below and also the location of the terraform index.

   [image]

   ```
   PS F:\terraform> terraform.exe init
   Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
   '"c:\python38\python.exe" "c:\Python38\Scripts\terraform.exe" init':
   the system cannot find the file specified.
   ```

   ```
   PS F:\terraform> ls


       Directory: F:\terraform

   Mode                 LastWriteTime          Length Name
   ----                 -------------          ------ ----
   d----          18-09-2021    22:21                 .terraform
   -a---          18-09-2021    22:33            1035 .terraform.lock.hcl
   -a---          18-09-2021    22:48             219 main.tf
   -a---          18-09-2021    22:48              41 provider.tf
   -----          18-09-2021    23:44        80807800 terraform.exe
   ```
3. I have tried to run the same code ps core 6 i get the above error message in the command prompt it works perfectly.

I really your inputs on what can be done.

Please help

Regards

Sudlo

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps which I performed to fix the issue.

I launched PS core prompt went into the directory in my case

`f:\terrform` and passed the command `terraform init` I got the same error message.

went into the location `C:\Python38\Scripts` and located the terraform executable file deleted the file and copied it again and performed initialization command. This time there was no error.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).